# update_callback not working on register_rest_field for more than one fields

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

My code is working perfectly for one field registered using `register_rest_field`. This work for both `get_callback` and `update_callback`. I am able get responses as expected from the rest endpoint. But the API crashes whenever I added more than one field to be registered. Though get_callback works great but posting an update to the API it will crash on the first update field registered. These are the code below

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_post_fields' );

// Register post fields.
function register_post_fields() {

// works if only this one field is added like below
    register_rest_field( 'post', 'source_name', array(
        'get_callback'    => 'get_post_source_name',
        'update_callback' => 'update_post_source_name',
        'schema' => array(
            'description' => __( 'Post views.' )
        ),
    ));

// On adding below code block for second field crashes on posting update
    register_rest_field( 'post', 'source_url', array(
        'get_callback'    => 'get_post_source_url',
        'update_callback' => 'update_post_source_url',
        'schema' => array(
            'description' => __( 'Post views.' ),
            'type'        => 'string'
        ),
    ));
}

function get_post_source_name( $post_obj ) {
    $post_id = $post_obj['id'];
    return get_post_meta($post_id, 'source_name', true);
}

function update_post_source_name( $value, $post, $key ) {
    $post_id = update_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, $value );
    if ( false === $post_id ) {
        return new WP_Error(
            'Update failed',
            __( 'Failed to update Source name.' ),
            array( 'status' => 500 )
        );
    }
    return true;
}

function get_post_source_url( $post_obj ) {
    $post_id = $post_obj['id'];
    return get_post_meta($post_id, 'source_url', true);
}

function update_post_source_url( $value, $post, $key ) {
    $post_id = update_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, $value );

    if ( false === $post_id ) {
        return new WP_Error(
            'Update failed',
            __( 'Failed to update Source url.' ),
            array( 'status' => 500 )
        );
    }
    return true;
}
```

My aim is to be able to add more than one rest field like this but posting  an update crashes the app by getting failed response from the first API.